# Variational Inference

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, variational-bayes

I have been looking at variational inference, however I came across a problem I have a hard time to understand how to start with it.

Let

$$\mu_n \sim N(\mu', \sigma'^2) \\ \tau_k \sim N(\tau', \lambda'^2)$$

where $\mu', \sigma', \tau', \lambda'$ are given parameters. Now let $$X_n \sim N(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \\ Y_k \sim N(\tau_k, \lambda_k^2)$$ where $\lambda_k, \sigma_n$ are given, however the mean $\mu_n$ and $\tau_k$ are stochastic variables (according to the distribution above).

We only observe the sum of the outcomes, i.e. $Z_n^k = Y_k + X_n$, so $Y_k$ and $X_n$ are hidden. Furthermore we observe some data for $n=1:N$, $k=1:K$. Now I want to approximate $p(\mu_{1:N}, \tau_{1:K} | Z_{1:N}^{1:K})$.

Now it want to express the joint probability. However now I get confused which variables should be included. According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods) (section "In practice") they seem to only include the hidden variables of interest and the observed data, i.e. the joint becomes:

$$p(\mu_{1:N}, \tau_{1:K}, Z_{1:N}^{1:K})$$

However, later on (in "A more complex example"), the seem to include all the stochastic variables and the observed data, i.e:

$$p(\mu_{1:N}, \tau_{1:K}, Z_{1:N}^{1:K}, X_{1:N}, Y_{1:K})$$

I was wondering which joint probability is correct to use in this model?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may start a bit too far 'at the beginning', but you can see from which point onwards I start talking about things that are new to you.

In Bayesian statistics $\mu_n$ and $\tau_k$ are called priors for $X_n$ and $Y_k$ respectively. The priors themselves have priors too, they are called hyper-priors (here $\sigma'$, $\mu'$, $\tau'$ and $\lambda'$). All hyper-priors are constants here. According to the problem statement $\sigma_n$ and $\lambda_k$ may be treated as deterministic as well.

I would say that the joint probability is the probability of all random variables, conditioned on all non-random (hyper)priors. In cases such as these, I like to use my newly learned trick: [Graphical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model). They allow to visually express the conditional dependencies of probability distributions. Also, the joint probability can be read of relatively easily. The graphical model for your problem looks like this:

[image: Graphical model]

The circled entities are random variables, whereas the others are deterministic. With the help of the graphical model, the joint probability is:

\begin{eqnarray}
P(&& X_{1:N}, \mu_{1:N}, Y_{1:K}, \tau_{1:K} | \sigma_{1:N}, \sigma', \mu', \tau', \lambda', \lambda_{1:K}) \\ 
= &&\prod_{n=1}^{N} \underbrace{P(X_n = x_n | \sigma_n, \mu_n)}_{\sim N(\mu_n, \sigma_n)}\underbrace{P(\mu_n | \sigma', \mu')}_{\sim N(\mu', \sigma')} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{K} \underbrace{P(Y_k = y_k | \tau_k, \lambda_k)}_{\sim N(\tau_k, \lambda_k)}\underbrace{P(\tau_k | \tau', \lambda')}_{\sim N(\tau', \lambda')}\\
= &&P(Z_{n,k} = z_{n,k} | \sigma_{1:N}, \mu', \sigma', \lambda_{1:K}, \tau', \lambda')
\end{eqnarray}

The last equality follows, by the fact that when $X_n$ and $Y_k$ are known, $Z_{n,k}$ is not a random variable anymore. Therefore, we can say that the joint probability here is also the probability distribution of $Z_{n,k}$.

As far as I know (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian) for details), the product of Gaussian variables does not result in another Gaussian or something else that's easy to work with (i.e. they are not [conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)). Therefore, I think this expression is the most appropriate representation of the joint probability.